# Need help printing a sequence, without spaces, on the same line

Tags: c++, for-loop, endl

so here is what i'm working with.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, h = -1;

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        h = h + 1;
        cout << h << endl;
    } // while

    return 0;
} // main
```

I need my output to look like

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

but I am getting

```
1
2
3
4
...
```

Is there anything besides `endl` you can use to print to the same line with spaces? thanks and sorry for the noob question. i'm am slowly learning c++.

Comment: Get a book about c++ and go through the samples. This way you'll learn c++ much faster. Read some manuals. Start here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cout/, here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/ and here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/endl/

Comment: This question makes no sense, sorry.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you want to print every number with a space in between.  If so then use an actual space instead of the end of line character

```
cout << h;
cout << ' ';
```

Then at the end of the loop explicitly add a new line

```
cout << endl;
```

Full Sample

```
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    h = h +1 ;
    cout << h << ' ';
  } 
  cout << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

cout << h << " "; will do the trick

Comment: For a single space `' '` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

`endl` is what prints the newline, so you should place that outside of the loop. Sample:

```
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
  h = h + 1;
  cout << h;
}
cout << endl;
```

Comment: this would print `01234567`, maybe not what the OP wants.

Comment: @hochl: You're right, I just read the question title which says "**without** spaces"...